# Creating Cognito userpools and dynamodbs on the fly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm creating an application using AWS Cognito which has the concept of a Company, and a Companies users.

A Company will have many Users but a User can only be associated with one Company. As a result I believe that I will need to create a new userpool for each set of Company Users whenever a new company is added. In addition I guess I will need to add a new set of dynamodb tables for each company.  So in short, I'll be creating new userpools and new dynamodb tables at run time whenever a new Company is created.
This to me seems dirty but I can't think of any other way.

Does this seem like a poor solution to my problem from an architecture perspective?

Comment: What's the dirty part, the architecture or creating on the fly?

Comment: well both i guess because they're one and the same.  1. having hundreds of userpools potentially, and also hundreds of instances of the dynamo db tables.   2. Creating it all on the fly.

Comment: Why not have a single Cognito User pool and a single DynamoDB table?  Unless you  have compliance reasons for segregating the data, creating hundreds of Cognito and DDB resources seems complicated.

Comment: Seth that would be ideal. But there's a possibility that the same user with the same email address would want to sign up to multiple companies. And it would not be ok to share the same user across multiple companies.